# PCI video card on a modern PCIE system

Tags: video, pci, pcie

I have a slightly older server (motherboard says it's a decade old. Oh well). The purpose of this server is "fast disks". So I have a PCIE x4 SATA card that drives 8 sata disks.
To get video output for say debugging the boot process I have an old PCI card with 1Mb video memory (yes 1Mb!). This will do just fine: Plenty for text-mode console.

The problem is that this card works through most of the boot process, except for the BIOS setup.
So then I "borrowed" a PCIE video card, running with "no disks" to get the install done.
And once I had done the BIOS setup and installed Ubuntu 20.04 I swapped the video cards back. Now the video card works during boot, but not the BIOS setup AND Linux. Lousy console!

Thinking about it: Could it be that by default the IO accesses to the VGA address space go to the PCIE slot and not the PCI slots?

The BIOS: Vendor: American Megatrends Inc. version 3.5
The motherboard: ASUSTeK Computer INC. P5QLD PRO

Can I arrange the IO accesses to be directed to PCI? From Linux? I can remote-access the machine right now. If it was in the BIOS that's going to be a pain: swap the video cards back, change the bios, make video not-work with the PCIE card etc.

Or do you think something else is going on?